# Definite integral gives trivial answer only among many other nontrivial possibilities

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
      Integrate[1/((I*zn - vF*(p - q/2))*(I*zn + I*wm + vF*(p 
      + q/2))),{zn, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions - 
      {Element[wm, Reals], vF > 0, Element[p, Reals], 
      Element[q, Reals]}]
```

Gives 0 as the answer for

```
       ConditionalExpression[0, (p <= 0 && q > -2*p) || (p > 0 
       && q > 2*p)]
```

But I did not specify this condition. So why does Mathematica assume what condition I have in mind instead of listing all possibilities?

Comment: Add, e.g., `q > 2 p, 2 p + q < 0` into the `Assumptions`. BTW there is a `>` missing.

Comment: Notice that in this  case `p > 0, q < 2 p, 2 p + q > 0` you get a nonzero answer `-((2 \[Pi])/(2 p vF + I wm))`

Comment: Why does Mathematica select the trivial answer by default when additional qualifiers are missing?